# Proof OLS is Biased if a Regressor is Correlated with the error

Tags: least-squares, bias

Consider the basic linear model:

$$y_i =\beta_0 +\beta_1 x_i +\varepsilon_i$$

I am aware that if $E[\varepsilon_i|x_i ]=0$ then $E[\hat{\beta_1}]=\beta_1$ (unbiasedness) and also that if $Cov(x_i,\varepsilon_i)=0$ then $plim \hat{\beta_1} = \beta_1$ (consistency).

I am hoping to prove that if $Cov(x_i,\varepsilon_i) \ne 0$ then $E[\hat{\beta_1}]\ne\beta_1$.
Can anyone help? My attempt begins below.

$$\hat{\beta_1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$

$$\hat{\beta_1}=\beta_1 + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})(\varepsilon_i-\bar{\varepsilon})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$

$$E[\hat{\beta_1}]=\beta_1 + E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})(\varepsilon_i-\bar{\varepsilon})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right]$$

My goal is to show the expectation on the right must be non-zero as a result of $Cov(x,\varepsilon)\ne 0$. The difficulty is that the expectation operator can be separately applied to the numerator and denominator. The numerator is in expectation non-zero, but if the sample covariance of $x$ and $\varepsilon$ is not independent of the sample variance of $x$, I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the expectation in the LHS of the third line of your display. The denominator is a constant and it is non-zero, so can be factored out of the expectation. $E(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x}) (\epsilon_i - \bar{\epsilon}))$ is by definition the covariance of the $x$ and $\epsilon$ vectors.

Comment: I am not convinced the denominator is constant, it depends on the draw of data.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. Remember that $\bar{\epsilon}=0$, you get:
$$
\hat{\beta}_1=\beta+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(\epsilon_i-\bar{\epsilon})}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}=\beta+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})\epsilon_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}
$$
Therefore
$$
E(\hat{\beta}_1 \vert x)=E\left(\left. \beta+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})\epsilon_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right|x\right)=\beta+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})E(\epsilon_i\vert x)}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\neq \beta
$$
since $E(\epsilon_i \vert x)\neq 0$. Since, $E(\hat{\beta}_1 \vert x) \neq \beta$ it follows that $E(\hat{\beta}_1)=E(E(\hat{\beta}_1 \vert x))\neq \beta$.

Comment: But how do we know that there is no other $E[\epsilon_i|x]$ (other than $E[\epsilon_i|x]=0$) such that $E[\hat{\beta}|x]=0$?
Does this proof definitely confirm no other  $E[\epsilon_i|x]$ is possible?

Comment: $E[\varepsilon|x]$ is a function, not necessarily a constant number, and I'm just looking for that final step (or, perhaps, missing why that step isn't necessary).

Comment: Basically, you need $E(\hat{\beta}_1 \vert x)=\beta$ for $\hat{\beta}_1$ to be consistent. If you look at the expression for $\hat{\beta}_1$, you see that this can only be the case if the last term is equal to zero. Conditional on $x$, the only thing that can make this expression equal to zero is $E(\epsilon_i \vert x)=0$ for all $i$. Thus, if you have one $E(\epsilon_i \vert x) \neq 0$ (no matter what the expression might look like), the result is $E(\hat{\beta}_1 \vert x) \neq \beta$.

Comment: But, suppose $E[\hat{\beta_1}|x]\ne \beta$ for some $x$, it may still be that $E[\hat{\beta_1}]=\beta.$ 
I feel like you have shown sufficiency, but not necessity of the condition $E[\epsilon_i|x]=0$ for unbiasedness.

Comment: If $E(\hat{\beta}_1 \vert x)\neq \beta$ it must hold by the law of iterated expectation that $E(\hat{\beta}_1 )=E(E(\hat{\beta}_1\vert x))\neq \beta$. Regarding sufficiency and necessity, do you mean that one can find such $x_1,\dots,x_n$ that, despite the fact that $E(\epsilon_i \vert x)\neq0$, the last term is equal to zero?

Comment: I'm not convinced of your first sentence. $E[\hat{\beta_1}|x]$ is a function, for each possible $x$, it takes a different value.
Suppose there is a draw of $x$, $x_1$, for which $E[\hat{\beta_1}|x_1]<\beta_1$ and another draw $x_2$ for which $E[\hat{\beta_1}|x_2]>\beta$, but on average, the truth is attained, $E[\hat{\beta_1}]=E[\hat{\beta_1}|x_1] Pr(x_1)+E[\hat{\beta_2}|x_1] Pr(x_2)=\beta$.

Comment: I'm trying to prove "If $Cov(x,\varepsilon)\ne 0$ then $E[\hat{\beta_1}]\ne \beta_1$. This is equivalent to "It is necessary for the error to be uncorrelated with the independent variable for estimates to be unbiased".
The proof I have seen (similar to what you're showing) is "If $E[\varepsilon|x]=0$, then  $E[\hat{\beta_1}] =\beta_1$". This is a sufficiency condition.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. Usually, this case is ruled out by making an assumption about the underlying data generating process. The assumption is that "$x$ may be fixed or random, but it is generated by a
mechanism that is unrelated to $\epsilon$." In particular, the expected value of $\epsilon_i$ is independent from all elements of $x$.  You can find detailed information about this assumption in Greene Econometric Analysis Chapter 2. Without that assumption you would be right though.

Comment: Are you referencing A3 from Greene? 
$E[\varepsilon_i|x_{j1},x_{j2},...,x_{jk}]=0$. "This states that the expected value of the disturbance at observation $i$ in the sample is not a function of the independent variables observed at any observation".
In the 7th edition, "fixed or random" is stated in 2-10, and in the previous sentence "mean of $\varepsilon_i$ is independent of all elements of $X$" (The A3 assumption). 

The proposition that is attempting to be proven begins with "If $Cov(x,\varepsilon)\ne 0$. Thus, I think we are necessarily assuming A3 fails in the statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132969/discussion-between-lars-and-michael-gmeiner).

Answer (score 1):

Woolridge does a really great job of explaining the unbiasedness of OLS coefficients in his book *Introductory Econometrics*. In what follows, I use his notation and arguments.

The assumption that $E(u\vert x)=E(u) = 0$ is a central assumption on OLS.  This assumption means that the error $u$ and the covariate $x$ are independent.  If the error and covariate are not independent (hence correlated), then $E(u\vert x) \neq 0 $ and will in genereal depend on $x$.

The proof that $\hat{\beta}_1$ is an unbiased estimate of $\beta_1$ makes use of this assumption.  Following Woolrdige...

$$\hat{\beta}_{1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right) y_{i}}{\operatorname{SST}_{x}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)\left(\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} x_{i}+u_{i}\right)}{\operatorname{SST}_{x}}$$

Here $\mathrm{SST}_{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)^{2}$.  Some commitment to doing some algebra yields

$$ \hat{\beta}_{1}=\beta_{1}+\left(1 / \operatorname{SST}_{x}\right) \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x}) u_{i} $$

If we take expectations in the above expression for $\hat{\beta}_1$, we obtain

$$ E(\hat{\beta}_1) = \beta_1 + 1/(\operatorname{SST}_x)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})E(u_i) $$

Note that since the error and predictor are not independent, $E(u_i)$ depends on $x$ and is not 0 in general, this the sum is not 0 leading to a bias.